Making sense of system responsiveness HDD utilization
The laptop in question:
HP ProBook 440 G5
OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
    Version 24H2 (OS Build 26100.1742)
CPU: Core i7-8550U
RAM: 16GB (2400 MT/s)
HDD: 1TB (Free Space: around ~90%)
Page File Size: 20GB

I am observing terrible responsiveness (far worse than these specs should be able to handle). It is used only for productivity tasks and has minimal software installed, including Chrome, Outlook, Word, etc. All software is up to date.
I recently upgraded RAM from 8GB to 16GB, which made the system somewhat usable. It still seems to freeze intermittently when switching between applications. Working on a single app seems to be OK. I increased the page file size to 20GB (more than the 16GB RAM installed), to no avail.
To add to the frustration, the performance and processes sections of the task manager make no sense to me (screenshots below).
Even though this is a new installation of Windows, I am about to:

Defragment the HDD
Run contig from Sysinternals
Run chkdsk c: /scan /perf /f /sdcleanup

There isn't much more I can do, is there? If the above steps do not help, how can I tell whether the system will support an SSD or NVMe and over what interface?
At this point, I am not even sure if the HDD is the only bottleneck. Any guidance on improving performance and/or choosing a faster drive would be appreciated.
Images:





Any system with SATA HDD supports the same form factor SATA SSD. And of course you should replace it for the OS. Running any modern OS in a 5400RPM HDD is ridiculous.
